# Dropdown list getting hided behind the popup

Tags: html, angular, angular6, kendo-grid

Hi I am using the kendo grid for displaying the data and in that one column is of dropdown list, but the values of dropdown list are getting behind the popup I tried by setting the property **z-index** for the dropdownlist but still its not working so please help.

[Image with original popup height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL5UT.png)

[Image after reducing the popup height manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CMPV.png)

drop down code

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Status Comment" width="200"   >
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate  >
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="statusCommentSource"   
      [textField]="'RejectionReason'"
      [valueField]="'RejectionCommentId'"  
      [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"           
      >
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Increase the `z-index` CSS property of the dropdown.

Comment: I increased it to 99999 still not working

Comment: Try setting the z-index after the user clicks the dropdown. That is, inside a function call do the manipulation. Somethig like `(click)="setZIndex(ele)"` and then `public setZIndex(element: string): void {
    // Ensures that pop-ups within the modal will open in front of the modal
    const elementSelected: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(element);

    if (elementSelected) {
      const elementToBringToFront: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>elementSelected.closest(".cdk-overlay-container");
      elementToBringToFront.style.zIndex = "1010";
    }
  }`